# Docker GitLab Runner cant load submodules

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab Runner that runs in Docker.

My project has submodules but when I try and build the project I get errors 
"fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or address"
"fatal: clone of 'https://gitlab.com/........"

Which makes sense as the docker instance won't have the user credentials, however I cant work out how to rectify.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and could get the Gitlab Runner to work in our Gitlab instance using the ssh url of the submodule.

```
[submodule "test"]
path = test
url = ssh://git@gitlab-instance.com/project/test.git
```